# Search column with comma separated string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Currently I am using the query below together with a recursive function to print a menu.

```
"SELECT * FROM categories WHERE FIND_IN_SET('".$parent."', parentId)"
```

DB structure:
 [image]

The result by printing this out is:

```
Smycken
--| Halsband
--|--| Guld
--|--|--| test
--|--|--|--| test2
--|--| Silver
--| Armband
Honung
```

Row 10, `parentId`. I got two values separated with a comma (I've read that this is not the ultimate way to store values, but I'll do it anyway), **now I want row 10 to be printed out like a subcategory, just like my other rows are being printed out.** The solution I found was to use FIND_IN_SET or use LIKE, I get neither of them to work as I wish...

Suggestions or a solution for my problem?

This is my function:

```
function getSubCat($level = 0, $parent = 0)
{                                               


$hasChildren = false;
$outputHtml = '%s';
$childrenHtml = '';

$dbh = getdbh();

$getSubCategory = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE FIND_IN_SET('".$parent."', parentId)");
$getSubCategory->execute();
$categories = $getSubCategory->fetchAll();
foreach($categories as $category)
{

    if ($category['parentId'] == $parent) {
        $hasChildren = true;
        $childrenHtml .= '<option value="'.$category['id'].'">';

        for($k = 0 ; $k < $level; $k++) {
            $childrenHtml .= '--|';
        }

        $childrenHtml .= ' '.$category['name'];
        $level++;
        $childrenHtml .= '</option>';
        $childrenHtml .= getSubCat($level, $category['id']);         
        $level--;                                                       
    }
}

if (!$hasChildren) {
    $outputHtml = '';
}

    return sprintf($outputHtml, $childrenHtml);
}
```

Comment: `find_in_set` should work. Is the a space after the comma in the `parentid` column? That would prevent it from working.

Comment: there is no space in that column. Values are passed like: "1,2,3,4"

Comment: The problem isn't in your SQL, it's in PHP. `if ($category['parentId'] == $parent)` does an exact match, it doesn't work if `$category['parentId']` has a comma.

Comment: I tried to make a `foreach` there and `explode(',', $str_from_DB)`. It is possible that I made something wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
if ($category['parentId'] == $parent) {
```

to:

```
if (in_array($parent, explode(',', $category['parentId']))) {
```

The `==` test won't look for an element in a comma-separated string.

Actually, you don't need this `if` at all. The `WHERE` clause in the SQL already guarantees that `$parent` is in `$category['parentId']`.

Comment: Thanks! I took away `if ($category['paren...` and now it works :)